# How to crop a part of the pdf in polygon shape using python

Tags: python

Using the following coordinates as vertices: `[(91,39), (190,36), (190,48), (91,51)]`
I am trying to crop a PDF `(width: 612, height:792)`

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter,PdfFileReader,PdfFileMerger
import itertools

for i in list(itertools.permutations([a,b,c,d],4)):
    pdf_file = PdfFileReader(open("IMG_7598.pdf","rb"))
    output=PdfFileWriter()
    i = [(91,39), (190,36), (190,48), (91,51)]

    page = pdf_file.getPage(0)
    # page.mediaBox.upperLeft= i[3]
    # page.mediaBox.upperRight= i[2]
    # page.mediaBox.lowerRight= i[1]
    # page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = i[0]

    page.cropBox.upperLeft= i[3]
    page.cropBox.upperRight= i[2]
    page.cropBox.lowerRight= i[1]
    page.cropBox.lowerLeft = i[0]

    output.addPage(page)
```

I have tried mediabox and Dropbox, both the methods give a rectangular shape even though the coordinates are for a polygon that's not a rectangle. Please advice.